# Javascript Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 on Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, button, addeventlistener

My HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript file

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.id = "test";
button.innerHTML = "Test";
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("hello");
});
var body = document.body;
body.appendChild(button);
```

I don't understand why when I click Test button, console of Chrome displays error **"Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1"** . But I realize that error appears only if I run it on localhost (I use apache of xampp as localhost) . If I run as normal file:// , it successes without any error

Comment: actually hello.js must be at the bottom of your html file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works fine for me....

But any ways please use window.onload function to do any stuff from javascript.

So do something like this

```
   window.onload = function(){
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id = "test";
        button.innerHTML = "Test";
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert("hello");
        });
        var body = document.body;
        body.appendChild(button);   
           }
```

Comment: thanks u. I checked, maybe chrome conficts with addon or anything else ... I run chrome with incognito mode (Ctr + Shift + N) , it doesn't any errors.